# Bash (OSX) / extra quick apache server

Tags: bash, apache, web

I have discovered drupal console couple of weeks ago.
Under the osx terminal, I can launch any drupal website using the following command : drupal server. Apache will then locally host the current folder and I can navigate the drupal site locally on my web browser. (by default http://127.0.0.1:8088/)
No need of create host.conf or such things, it's super quick.

Is there any way to do it without drupal?
Can I host any folder with a single command line?

Thanks a lot for your response.

Pierre

Comment: `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080` is the simplest I can think of. Also look at `man httpd` and `man nc`.

Comment: With some work, using Apache vhosts conf and dnsmasq, you can create a local hosted website just by creating a new folder and the given folder name will be the website address you can access (of course, you need Apache running first). Here is a tutorial I found, http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/local-development-apache-vhosts-and-dnsmasq

Comment: Many modern programming languages come with web server libraries which do this out of the box. https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html and I imagine you would easily find something similar for Ruby, Perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Siguza and Lin. Both answer are great.
I copy them below for possible apprentice like me who read that post...

solution 1:

php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 is the simplest I can think of. Also look at man httpd and man nc. – Siguza 9 hours ago

solution 2:
With some work, using Apache vhosts conf and dnsmasq, you can create a local hosted website just by creating a new folder and the given folder name will be the website address you can access (of course, you need Apache running first). Here is a tutorial I found, fourkitchens.com/blog/article/… – Lin 2 hours ago